# Scraping a csv file

Tags: r, database, csv, web-scraping, rvest

I'm trying to save a two csv files that can be accessed through this website:

https://www.cenace.gob.mx/Paginas/SIM/Reportes/CapacidadTransferencia.aspx

I only want to save both csv files as data frames in RStudio. I've tried to do this through rvest, but it seems that the data is in the website's back end and this approach is not working.

Comment: it does a POST request upon icon click - you can view in dev tools of browser.

Comment: try `RSelenium`